# java code sqlite database not being created in android studio

Tags: java, android-sqlite

`Hello so i'm a noobie coder and im trying to code this mobile app on android studio that tracks ur current location and then sends it over to sqlite database when the "start journey" button is being clicked. (location & timestamp will be sent over) . Similarly for the "end journey" button.
however the error im encountering right now is that whenever i click the "start journey" button, the mobile app auto exits itself. There are also no databases created if i check at the /data/data//databases directory under device explorer in android studio.
What may be the problem?

Tried chatgpt but did not get much useful input hence asking here.
Below are my mainactivity.java , activity_main.xml, and DatabaseHelper.java

Exceeded max word count limited so i removed my imports** just assume i have all of the neccessary imports.

```
Mainactivity.java :
package com.verdefy;
import com.verdefy.DatabaseHelper;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleMap map;
    private CameraPosition cameraPosition;

    // The entry point to the Places API.
    private PlacesClient placesClient;

    // The entry point to the Fused Location Provider.
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    // A default location (Singapore) and default zoom to use when location permission is
    // not granted.
    private final LatLng defaultLocation = new LatLng(1.3521, 103.8198);

    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private boolean locationPermissionGranted;

    // The geographical location where the device is currently located. That is, the last-known
    // location retrieved by the Fused Location Provider.
    private Location lastKnownLocation;

    // Keys for storing activity state.

    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";

    // Used for selecting the current place.
    private static final int M_MAX_ENTRIES = 5;
    private String[] likelyPlaceNames;
    private String[] likelyPlaceAddresses;
    private List[] likelyPlaceAttributions;
    private LatLng[] likelyPlaceLatLngs;

    // Variables for location tracking
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private float totalDistance = 0;

    private SendDataToDatabase sendDataToDatabase;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sendDataToDatabase = new SendDataToDatabase();

        // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            lastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            cameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }
        // [END maps_current_place_on_create_save_instance_state]
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Construct a PlacesClient; Initializes Places SDK for android with the API key
        //stored in the buildconfig class
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.PLACES_API_KEY);
        placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

        // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        //Build the map and start it
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        //end

        //initialize updateDistanceTextView

        // Initialize locationCallback
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            // Define the method inside your class (e.g., MainActivity)
            private void updateDistanceTextView(float distance) {
                // Assuming you have a TextView named distanceTextView
                TextView distanceTextView = findViewById(R.id.distanceTextView);
                if (distanceTextView != null) {
                    distanceTextView.setText("Distance: " + distance + " meters");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult); //Call superclass method if needed
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (lastLocation != null) {
                        float distance = lastLocation.distanceTo(location);
                        totalDistance += distance;
                        updateDistanceTextView(totalDistance);
                    }
                    lastLocation = location;
                }
            }
        };

// Inside onCreate() or any appropriate method
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000); // Update interval in milliseconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000); // Fastest update interval in milliseconds
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); // Set priority
        // [END maps_current_place_on_create]
    }

    // Start location updates



    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    /**
     * Saves the state of the map when the activity is paused.
     */

    // [START maps_current_place_on_save_instance_state]
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (map != null && lastKnownLocation!= null) {

            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, lastKnownLocation);
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_on_save_instance_state]

    /**
     * Sets up the options menu.
     *
     * @param menu The options menu.
     * @return Boolean.
     */


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.current_place_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handles a click on the menu option to get a place.
     *
     * @param item The menu item to handle.
     * @return Boolean.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_on_options_item_selected]
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.option_get_place) {
            showCurrentPlace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    // [END maps_current_place_on_options_item_selected]

    /**
     * Manipulates the map when it's available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_on_map_ready]
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        this.map = map;

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // [START map_current_place_set_info_window_adapter]
        // Use a custom info window adapter to handle multiple lines of text in the
        // info window contents.
        this.map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            // Return null here, so that getInfoContents() is called next.
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Inflate the layouts for the info window, title and snippet.
                View infoWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents,
                        (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.map), false);

                TextView title = infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView snippet = infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
                snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                return infoWindow;
            }
        });
        // [END map_current_place_set_info_window_adapter]

        // Prompt the user for permission.
        getLocationPermission();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
        updateLocationUI();

        // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
        getDeviceLocation();
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_on_map_ready]

    /**
     * Gets the current location of the device, and positions the map's camera.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_get_device_location]
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            lastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                        new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_get_device_location]

    /**
     * Prompts the user for permission to use the device location.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_location_permission]
    private void getLocationPermission() {
        /*
         * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
         * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
         * onRequestPermissionsResult.
         */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_location_permission]

    /**
     * Handles the result of the request for location permissions.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_on_request_permissions_result]
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        locationPermissionGranted = false;
        if (requestCode
                == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) {// If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationPermissionGranted = true;
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_on_request_permissions_result]

    /**
     * Prompts the user to select the current place from a list of likely places, and shows the
     * current place on the map - provided the user has granted location permission.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_show_current_place]
    private void showCurrentPlace() {
        if (map == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (locationPermissionGranted) {
            // Use fields to define the data types to return.
            List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS,
                    Place.Field.LAT_LNG);

            // Use the builder to create a FindCurrentPlaceRequest.
            FindCurrentPlaceRequest request =
                    FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeFields);

            // Get the likely places - that is, the businesses and other points of interest that
            // are the best match for the device's current location.
            @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission") final Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> placeResult =
                    placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request);
            placeResult.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FindCurrentPlaceResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        FindCurrentPlaceResponse likelyPlaces = task.getResult();

                        // Set the count, handling cases where less than 5 entries are returned.
                        int count;
                        if (likelyPlaces.getPlaceLikelihoods().size() < M_MAX_ENTRIES) {
                            count = likelyPlaces.getPlaceLikelihoods().size();
                        } else {
                            count = M_MAX_ENTRIES;
                        }

                        int i = 0;
                        likelyPlaceNames = new String[count];
                        likelyPlaceAddresses = new String[count];
                        likelyPlaceAttributions = new List[count];
                        likelyPlaceLatLngs = new LatLng[count];

                        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces.getPlaceLikelihoods()) {
                            // Build a list of likely places to show the user.
                            likelyPlaceNames[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName();
                            likelyPlaceAddresses[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress();
                            likelyPlaceAttributions[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                                    .getAttributions();
                            likelyPlaceLatLngs[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng();

                            i++;
                            if (i > (count - 1)) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        // Show a dialog offering the user the list of likely places, and add a
                        // marker at the selected place.
                        MainActivity.this.openPlacesDialog();
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The user has not granted permission.
            Log.i(TAG, "The user did not grant location permission.");

            // Add a default marker, because the user hasn't selected a place.
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(getString(R.string.default_info_title))
                    .position(defaultLocation)
                    .snippet(getString(R.string.default_info_snippet)));

            // Prompt the user for permission.
            getLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_show_current_place]

    /**
     * Displays a form allowing the user to select a place from a list of likely places.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_open_places_dialog]
    private void openPlacesDialog() {
        // Ask the user to choose the place where they are now.
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // The "which" argument contains the position of the selected item.
                LatLng markerLatLng = likelyPlaceLatLngs[which];
                String markerSnippet = likelyPlaceAddresses[which];
                if (likelyPlaceAttributions[which] != null) {
                    markerSnippet = markerSnippet + "\n" + likelyPlaceAttributions[which];
                }

                // Add a marker for the selected place, with an info window
                // showing information about that place.
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(likelyPlaceNames[which])
                        .position(markerLatLng)
                        .snippet(markerSnippet));

                // Position the map's camera at the location of the marker.
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markerLatLng,
                        DEFAULT_ZOOM));
            }
        };

        // Display the dialog.
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.pick_place)
                .setItems(likelyPlaceNames, listener)
                .show();
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_open_places_dialog]

    /**
     * Updates the map's UI settings based on whether the user has granted location permission.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_update_location_ui]
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (map == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            } else {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                lastKnownLocation = null;
                getLocationPermission();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_update_location_ui]


    private String getLocationName(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // Your implementation to get the location name based on latitude and longitude
        // This method should return the name of the location based on the provided coordinates
        // You may use geocoding or reverse geocoding to achieve this
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                return address.getAddressLine(0); // You can customize this as per your requirements
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private String getCurrentTimestamp() {
        // Get current timestamp
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String timestamp = sdf.format(new Date());
        return timestamp;
    }

    // Your class definition
    public class SendDataToDatabase {

        // Your other methods

        //START a journey and start tracking
        // Send location and timestamp to the database
        // Start tracking user's location
        // You can use the Google Maps Directions API to calculate distance and carbon emission
        // Start a timer or capture the start time for duration calculation
        public void startJourney(View view) {
            // Get current location and timestamp
            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                String startLocation = getLocationName(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                String startTimeStamp = getCurrentTimestamp();

                // Assuming addTravelData is a method of DatabaseHelper class
                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this); // Assuming this is your activity context
                dbHelper.addTravelData(startLocation, startTimeStamp,null, null);
            }
        }


        // END A JOURNEY, stop all tracking
        public void endJourney(View view) {
            // Stop tracking user's location
            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                String endLocation = getLocationName(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                String endTimeStamp = getCurrentTimestamp();

                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                // Save end location and timestamp to the database
                dbHelper.addTravelData(null,null, endLocation, endTimeStamp);
            }
            // Calculate distance travelled
            // Calculate time duration
            // Calculate carbon emission if possible
            // Send all captured data (distance, duration, type of vehicle, etc.) to the database
        }

        // Method to handle start journey button click
        public void onStartJourneyButtonClick(View view) {
            sendDataToDatabase.startJourney(view);
        }

        // Method to handle end journey button click
        public void onEndJourneyButtonClick(View view) {
            sendDataToDatabase.endJourney(view);
        }

    }



    }
```

```
2) Activity_main.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_green"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NewJourneyTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/jua"
        android:text="Start a New Journey"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/map"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.178" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:onClick="onStartJourneyButtonClick"
        android:text="Start Journey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EndButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:onClick="onEndJourneyButtonClick"
        android:text="End Journey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="444dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distanceTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Distance: "
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
3)DatabaseHelper.java
package com.verdefy;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.ContentValues;



// Create the database
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASENAME = "VERDEFY";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        public static final String TABLE_TRAVELDATA = "travel_data";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_STARTLOCATION = "startLocation";
        public static final String COLUMN_ENDLOCATION = "endLocation";
        public static final String COLUMN_STARTTIMESTAMP = "startTimeStamp";
    public static final String COLUMN_ENDTIMESTAMP = "endTimeStamp";

        private static final String TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRAVELDATA + " (" +
                        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        COLUMN_STARTLOCATION + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_ENDLOCATION + " TEXT, " +
                        COLUMN_STARTTIMESTAMP + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
                        COLUMN_ENDTIMESTAMP + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASENAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TRAVELDATA);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    // Add this method to your DatabaseHelper class
    public void addTravelData(String startLocation, String startTimeStamp, String endLocation,  String endTimeStamp) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_STARTLOCATION, startLocation);
        values.put(COLUMN_STARTTIMESTAMP, startTimeStamp);
        values.put(COLUMN_ENDLOCATION, endLocation);
        values.put(COLUMN_ENDTIMESTAMP, endTimeStamp);
        db.insert(TABLE_TRAVELDATA, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant part ( e.g. the start journey code) at the moment it is way too much code and most irrelevant. On the other hand your question is missing the error you get when your appp crashes. Get it from logcat and include it in your question and remove all the unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the database code e.g. using your DatabaseHelper class, copied asis and then the following activity code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper dbh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dbh.addTravelData("Here",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()),"There",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        Cursor csr = dbh.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TRAVELDATA,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

Then then log includes:-

```
2024-02-27 05:37:11.428 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@d598771
2024-02-27 05:37:11.428 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-02-27 05:37:11.428 I/System.out:    _id=1
2024-02-27 05:37:11.429 I/System.out:    startLocation=Here
2024-02-27 05:37:11.429 I/System.out:    endLocation=There
2024-02-27 05:37:11.429 I/System.out:    startTimeStamp=1708972631288
2024-02-27 05:37:11.429 I/System.out:    endTimeStamp=1708972631288
2024-02-27 05:37:11.429 I/System.out: }
2024-02-27 05:37:11.429 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- which shows that the row has been added and retrieved from the database.

Using App Inspection shows:-

[image]

- i.e. that the database is accessible via App Inspection, and has the expected single row.

As such the assumption that the issue is with the database is very likely not the case.

You have reams of code which appear to require libraries. Simply put the question has not been asked according to StackOverflow guidelines.

Even more importantly you indicate that you have attempted little in the way of debugging the issue when you say:-

> however the error im encountering right now is that whenever i click the "start journey" button, the mobile app auto exits itself.

The first thing to do is **look at the Log**, this will have an exception that will point you to where the failure occurred.

- You may wish to read https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/ first.
- You should then probably refer to the section https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#systemLogView

At a guess your issue may well something along the lines of:-

```
2024-02-27 06:19:46.237 26545-26545/a.a.so78062371javasqlitedb E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: a.a.so78062371javasqlitedb, PID: 26545
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onStartJourneyButtonClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'startButton'
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:506)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:464)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1218)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

If this is the case, the the issue is with the button and it's onClick handling.

Using a subset of your activty_main.xml to add the two buttons, as per:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:text="Start Journey"
        android:onClick="onStartJourneyButtonClick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,OnClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EndButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:text="End Journey"
        android:onClick="onEndJourneyButtonClick"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,OnClick" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then running the app and then clicking either button results in the exception above.

Amending the Main Activity code to actually assign the buttons to respective variables and to include the SendDataToDatabase class (modified to just add some data), as per:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button startButton,endButton;
    SendDataToDatabase sendDataToDatabase;
    DatabaseHelper dbh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sendDataToDatabase = new SendDataToDatabase();
        startButton = this.findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        endButton = this.findViewById(R.id.EndButton);
        dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dbh.addTravelData("Here",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()),"There",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        Cursor csr = dbh.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TRAVELDATA,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }

    public class SendDataToDatabase {

        // Your other methods

        //START a journey and start tracking
        // Send location and timestamp to the database
        // Start tracking user's location
        // You can use the Google Maps Directions API to calculate distance and carbon emission
        // Start a timer or capture the start time for duration calculation
        public void startJourney(View view) {
            // Get current location and timestamp
            /*
            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                String startLocation = getLocationName(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                String startTimeStamp = getCurrentTimestamp();

                // Assuming addTravelData is a method of DatabaseHelper class
                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this); // Assuming this is your activity context
                dbHelper.addTravelData(startLocation, startTimeStamp,null, null);
            }
             */
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper((MainActivity.this));
            dbHelper.addTravelData(null,null, "AHere" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "AThere" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }


        // END A JOURNEY, stop all tracking
        public void endJourney(View view) {
            // Stop tracking user's location
            /*
            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                String endLocation = getLocationName(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                String endTimeStamp = getCurrentTimestamp();

                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                // Save end location and timestamp to the database
                dbHelper.addTravelData(null,null, endLocation, endTimeStamp);
            }
            */
            // Calculate distance travelled
            // Calculate time duration
            // Calculate carbon emission if possible
            // Send all captured data (distance, duration, type of vehicle, etc.) to the database
            DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper((MainActivity.this));
            dbHelper.addTravelData(null,null, "EHere" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "EThere" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        // Method to handle start journey button click
        public void onStartJourneyButtonClick(View view) {
            sendDataToDatabase.startJourney(view);
        }

        // Method to handle end journey button click
        public void onEndJourneyButtonClick(View view) {
            sendDataToDatabase.endJourney(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Again results in the same exception (when either button is clicked).

**HOWEVER** if onClick listeners are set using:-

```
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendDataToDatabase.startJourney(view);
        }
    });
    endButton = this.findViewById(R.id.EndButton);
    endButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendDataToDatabase.endJourney(view);
        }
    });
```

Then, when the App is started then:-

[image]

And App Inspection shows:-

[image]

Clicking the START JOURNEY button doesn't exist and App Inspection then shows:-

[image]

Clicking the END JOURNEY button likes works and App Inspection shows:-

[image]

**As such, based upon a cut down version of your code, it is quite likely that your issue is with the handling of the buttons**. You may wish to include the following code in the `onCreate` method of MainActivity:-

```
    startButton = this.findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendDataToDatabase.startJourney(view);
        }
    });
    endButton = this.findViewById(R.id.EndButton);
    endButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendDataToDatabase.endJourney(view);
        }
    });
```

If you wish to utilise the DEFAULT values when passing null (for startTimeStamp and endTimeStamp) then you may wish to consider changing the `addTravelData` method to be:-

```
public void addTravelData(String startLocation, String startTimeStamp, String endLocation,  String endTimeStamp) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_STARTLOCATION, startLocation);
    if (startTimeStamp!= null) values.put(COLUMN_STARTTIMESTAMP, startTimeStamp);
    values.put(COLUMN_ENDLOCATION, endLocation);
    if (endTimeStamp != null) values.put(COLUMN_ENDTIMESTAMP, endTimeStamp);
    db.insert(TABLE_TRAVELDATA, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

- i.e. the values are not `put` into the ContentValues if they are NULL and hence the DEFAULT will be used.

This will then (as the startTimeStamp is null) result in (see the highlighted  data) :-

[image]

At a guess you would want to consider which values should be passed as null.

An additional aspect, that confuses many, is that when you instantiate a class that extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class, such as your `DatabaseHelper` class, is that the `onCreate` is not called at that time. It is only when an attempt is made to access the database that the database itself will be created or opened (the latter if the database already exists). So at is only after this attempt to access the database that it will then be created. Hence as you very likely encountered an exception prior to the attempt to access the database the database will not have been created.

Comment: whoa i just want to thank you for giving such an detailed explanation!! i finally understand the code a little more and i now know where to troubleshoot my errors!!!  I have now changed my code to using ur method instead, by specifying a button in the mainactivity.java file and then using the onClickListener method..However  i checked app inspector | device explorer & the database is still not created .... :(( still, words cant express how grateful i am becuz im rlly lost since this is the first project im coding thank you!!

Comment: I'd suggest **temporarily** adding code, like in the example, to the `onCreate` method of the activity to access the database (e.g. to add a row as per `dbh.addTravelData("Here",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()),"There",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));`) if that works and creates the database then you know that the click listeners are probably not doing what you expect. You could then add a breakpoint and then run in debug mode e.g. breakpoint on `if (lastKnownLocation != null) {`